# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present, disable CORS but still not working

Tags: javascript, axios

Is there anyway I can solve this error? I have tried putting "  " and also in the request header, but it doesnt work

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```
axios.post("https://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api?food_id=33691&method=food.get.v2&oauth_consumer_key=9a1a6fd1fff5433f9dd77daa4587bf5d&oauth_nonce=1234&oauth_signature=sAyYTJiIxOGkvFpBcH8L%2BlFQRCQ%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1245126631&oauth_version=1.0",{
            })
            .then(response=>{
                console.log(response.data);

                }
            
            )
            .catch(error=>{
                alert("wrong");
                console.log(error)
            })
```

Comment: Search on SO and you will find plenty of similar questions for that exact same problem/error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

Comment: `fatsecret.com/rest/server.api` does not permit direct embedding of their data.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, You need to allow it from the server side. Otherwise, you will get this error.

Comment: how do I allow it from the server side ?

Comment: Can you tell me which server/backend framework you're using ?